# How do you find an object in an array based on a property of the object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array, "entries". The array is made up of objects, each object representing an entry in the database. Each object has a bunch of properties, id, first name, last name, dob, island, etc.

I am creating a table based on these objects, and there is a checkbox for each object, with the ID of the object as the value of the checkbox.

I have a function that checks if the checkboxes are ticked, and if they are, it returns the values of the ticked checkboxes.

I also have these stored in another array, checkedEntries.

For example, there is a delete button, so you'd check the box, hit delete and then my app asks for confirmation that you want to delete these entries. At the moment, it is only displaying the entry ID numbers. I want to take the numbers in checkedEntries, and use them to find the corresponding object in the entries array, and pull out some properties.

I want to do this so that the delete confirmation can be a little more precise, so you can get a better idea of what you are doing.

So, in the end, how do I search an array by it's objects properties, and then get access to said properties?

I don't mind finding the index of the entry that corresponds to the ID, as then I can pull the data out based on the index.

EDIT: I don't want to use JQuery, just plain javascript.

Here's the arrays:

```
let entries = [
  {
    id: "0002",
    photo: "#",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    dateOfBirth: "01/24/1990"
  },
  {
    id: "0003",
    photo: "#",
    firstName: "Aaron",
    lastName: "Smith",
    dateOfBirth: "02/13/1985"
  },
];

// Check for checked checkboxes
function getSelectedCheckboxValues(name) {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
  let values = [];
  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    values.push(checkbox.value);
  });
  return values;
}

let checkedEntries = getSelectedCheckboxValues("entry");
```

Comment: How is your HTML (`input[name="entry"]`) looks like?

Comment: Take a look at the map-method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Comment: @Mamun, my HTML is fine. I am successfully getting the ID's from the checkbox's value attribute and adding them to the array 'checkedEntries'. That part works. I am trying to figure out how to write a function that for every index of checkedEntries, it looks at the main entries array, finds the object based on the ID property, and then returns that object, or the index of that object so I can then pull out the properties of said object.

Comment: how about using ARRAY.fiter (item=> return if( item.condition === true)